# Python processing CSV file really slow

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

So I am trying to open a CSV file, read its fields and based on that fix some other fields and then save that data back to csv. My problem is that the CSV file has 2 million rows. What would be the best way to speed this up.
The CSV file consists of

```
ID; DATE(d/m/y); SPECIAL_ID; DAY; MONTH; YEAR
```

I am counting how often a row with the same date appears on my record and then update SPECIAL_ID based on that data.

Based on my previous research I decided to use pandas. I'll be processing even bigger sets of data in future (1-2GB) - this one is around 119MB so it crucial I find a good fast solution.

My code goes as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';') 
df_fixed= pd.DataFrame(columns=stolpci) #when I process the row in df I append it do df_fixed
d = 31
m = 12
y = 100
s = (y,m,d)
list_dates= np.zeros(s) #3 dimensional array. 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # PROCESSING LOGIC GOES HERE
    # IT CONSISTS OF FEW IF STATEMENTS
    list_dates[row.DAY][row.MONTH][row.YEAR] += 1
    row['special_id'] = list_dates[row.DAY][row.MONTH][row.YEAR]
    df_fixed = df_fixed.append(row.to_frame().T)


df_fixed .to_csv(filename_fixed, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

I tried to make a print for every thousand rows processed. At first, my script needs 3 seconds for 1000 rows, but the longer it runs the slower it gets.
at row 43000 it needs 29 seconds and so on...

Thanks for all future help :)

EDIT: 
I am adding additional information about my CSV and exptected output

```
ID;SPECIAL_ID;sex;age;zone;key;day;month;year
2;13012016505__-;F;1;1001001;1001001_F_1;13;1;2016
3;25122013505__-;F;4;1001001;1001001_F_4;25;12;2013
4;24022012505__-;F;5;1001001;1001001_F_5;24;2;2012
5;09032012505__-;F;5;1001001;1001001_F_5;9;3;2012
6;21082011505__-;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;21;8;2011
7;16082011505__-;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;16;8;2011
8;21102011505__-;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;16;8;2011
```

I have to replace **- in the special ID field to a proper number.
For example for a row with
ID = 2 the SPECIAL_ID will be 
26022018505001  (**- got replaced by 001) if someone else in the CSV shares the same DAY, MONTH, YEAR the __- will be replaced by 002 and so on...
So exptected output for above rows would be

```
ID;SPECIAL_ID;sex;age;zone;key;day;month;year
2;13012016505001;F;1;1001001;1001001_F_1;13;1;2016
3;25122013505001;F;4;1001001;1001001_F_4;25;12;2013
4;24022012505001;F;5;1001001;1001001_F_5;24;2;2012
5;09032012505001;F;5;1001001;1001001_F_5;9;3;2012
6;21082011505001;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;21;8;2011
7;16082011505001;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;16;8;2011
8;21102011505002;F;6;1001001;1001001_F_6;16;8;2011
```

EDIT:
I changed my code to something like this: I fill list of dicts with data and then convert that list do dataframe and save as csv. This will take around 30minutes to complete

```
list_popravljeni = []
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
df_dates = df.groupby(by=['dan_roj', 'mesec_roj', 'leto_roj']).size().reset_index() 
    for index, row in df_dates.iterrows():
        df_candidates= df.loc[(df['dan_roj'] == dan_roj) & (df['mesec_roj'] == mesec_roj) & (df['leto_roj'] == leto_roj) ]
        for index, row in df_candidates.iterrows():
            vrstica = {}
            vrstica['ID'] = row['identifikator']
            vrstica['SPECIAL_ID'] = row['emso'][0:11] + str(index).zfill(2)
            vrstica['day'] = row['day']
            vrstica['MONTH'] = row['MONTH']
            vrstica['YEAR'] = row['YEAR']   
            list_popravljeni.append(vrstica)
    pd.DataFrame(list_popravljeni, columns=list_popravljeni[0].keys())
```

Comment: one way to reduce the search space might be to use pandas slices to replace your IF conditions. E.g. if value > 5 can be sliced to `df.loc[df['value']>5,:]` will trim your dataset down to only those rows that match your if conditions. This assumes you are looking for one outcome that matches all the conditions.

Comment: Can you please include a small example of your input file and the expected output in this case? DataFrames are not optimised for `for` loops or being appended to millions of times, but it's hard to properly visualise a vectorized approach without an example to check against.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use something like `df = df.groupby(by=['year', 'month', 'day']).size().reset_index()`. This will count occurrences of a particular date.

Comment: @roganjosh I did :) check the edited post

Comment: okay @roganjosh I tried as you suggested and groupby works perfectly! I didn't even know what option existed in pandas. 
Now I have to assign those numbers to actual records..

Comment: I'm having a bit at a go at the string concatenation side to complete your question but honestly I haven't got much time available so probably someone else will have to complete the solution for you sorry. But yeah, the main rule is to avoid iteration at all costs, that runs in Python time so you lose pretty much all the benefits of pandas/numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives what you're looking for and avoids looping. Potentially it could be more efficient (I wasn't able to find a way to avoid creating `counts`). However, it should be much faster than your current approach.

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day'])['SPECIAL_ID'].cumcount() + 1
df['counts'] = df['counts'].astype(str)
df['counts'] = df['counts'].str.zfill(3)
df['SPECIAL_ID'] = df['SPECIAL_ID'].str.slice(0, -3).str.cat(df['counts'])
```

I added a fake record at the end to confirm it does increment properly:

```
     SPECIAL_ID sex age     zone          key day month  year counts
0  13012016505001   F   1  1001001  1001001_F_1  13     1  2016    001
1  25122013505001   F   4  1001001  1001001_F_4  25    12  2013    001
2  24022012505001   F   5  1001001  1001001_F_5  24     2  2012    001
3  09032012505001   F   5  1001001  1001001_F_5   9     3  2012    001
4  21082011505001   F   6  1001001  1001001_F_6  21     8  2011    001
5  16082011505001   F   6  1001001  1001001_F_6  16     8  2011    001
6  21102011505002   F   6  1001001  1001001_F_6  16     8  2011    002
7  21102012505003   F   6  1001001  1001001_F_6  16     8  2011    003
```

If you want to get rid of `counts`, you just need:

```
df.drop('counts', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for help! and yes count should increment. record#5[SPECIAL_ID] should 16082011505001 and record#6[SPECIAL_ID] should be 16082011505002

Comment: @Kristjan but it increments specifically based on the ordering in the `ID` column? Because I think `groupby` will destroy any of the initial ordering so we need something fixed to base this on, otherwise it'll be arbitrary which gets `001` and which gets `002`

Comment: at this stage it doesn't matter who gets which number. I just need all records for a given day get number 1 - len(records_on_given_day)
I managed to speed it up. I think it will take around 30-40minutes to complete... but still better than my old way. I'll post my solution as an answer when I find some time... If you think even faster way is possible my ears are open

Comment: @Kristjan I have fixed the issue. I expect my approach to be in the order of seconds, not minutes.

Comment: Great, I incorporated your answer into my code and it works perfectly and really fast! I'll be doing a lot of work like that above in the future, so if you could point me to a good learning resource it would be really great.

Comment: @Kristjan I'm glad it works. As for learning material, I can't be much help there I'm afraid :/ Pandas is pretty huge and non-intuitive in some cases. Your best bet is probably to follow some of the bigger names here for a bit e.g. Jezrael, MaxU, Coldspeed, Wen, Unutbu, to name a few (and plenty that I missed out, sorry!). piRSquared seems to be using more pandas these days too.